# How do I know why my SonarQube helm chart is getting auto-killed by Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, devops

This question is about logging/monitoring.

I'm running a 3 node cluster on AKS, with 3 orgs, Dev, Test and Prod. The chart worked fine in Dev, but the same chart keeps getting killed by Kubernetes in Test, and it keeps getting recreated, and re-killed. Is there a way to extract details on why this is happening? All I see when I describe the pod is Reason: Killed

Please tell me more details on this or can give some suggestions. Thanks!

Comment: So there could be different reasons for this behavior, have you configured a liveness probe ? can you check whether its failing or not ? And are you having auto scales setup ? 
Can you get the output of : kubectl get events

Answer (score 1):

## List Events sorted by timestamp

kubectl get events --sort-by=.metadata.creationTimestamp

Answer (score 1):

There might be various reasons for it to be killed, e.g. not sufficient resources or [failed liveness probe](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/pod-lifecycle/#container-probes).

For SonarQube there is a [liveness and readiness probe](https://github.com/helm/charts/blob/7e45e678e39b88590fe877f159516f85f3fd3f38/stable/sonarqube/templates/deployment.yaml#L205) configured so it might fail. Also as described in [helm's chart values](https://github.com/helm/charts/blob/7e45e678e39b88590fe877f159516f85f3fd3f38/stable/sonarqube/values.yaml#L79):

> If an ingress *path* other than the root (/) is defined, it should be reflected here
> A trailing "/" must be included

You can also check if there are sufficient resources on node:

- check what node are pods running on: `kubectl get pods -test` and
  then run `kubectl describe node <node-name>` to check if there is no
  disk/ memory pressure.

You can also run `kubectl logs <pod-name>` and `kubectl describe pod <pod-name>` that might give you some insight of kill reason.